# Dask job fails in Jupyter notebook cell with KilledWorker

Tags: jupyter-notebook, dask

I am running a join task in a Jupyter notebook which is producing many warnings from Dask about a possible memory leak before finally failing with a killed worker error:

```
2022-07-26 21:38:05,726 - distributed.worker_memory - WARNING - Worker is at 85% memory usage. Pausing worker.  Process memory: 1.59 GiB -- Worker memory limit: 1.86 GiB
2022-07-26 21:38:06,319 - distributed.worker_memory - WARNING - Unmanaged memory use is high. This may indicate a memory leak or the memory may not be released to the OS; see https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/worker-memory.html#memory-not-released-back-to-the-os for more information. -- Unmanaged memory: 1.59 GiB -- Worker memory limit: 1.86 GiB
2022-07-26 21:38:07,501 - distributed.worker_memory - WARNING - Worker tcp://127.0.0.1:46137 (pid=538697) exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting...
2022-07-26 21:38:07,641 - distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker

KilledWorker: ("('assign-6881b18750807133ba976bf463a98c23', 0)", <WorkerState 'tcp://127.0.0.1:46137', name: 0, status: closed, memory: 0, processing: 50>)
```

This happens when I run my code on a laptop with 32GB RAM (Kubuntu 20). Maybe I have not configured Dask correctly for the environment? I can watch the memory usage go up and down in the system monitor but at no point does it consume all the memory. How can I tell Dask to use all the cores and as much memory as it can manage? It seems to be running in single processor mode, maybe because I'm running on a laptop rather than a proper cluster?

For context: I'm joining two datasets, both are text files with sizes 25GB and 5GB. Both files have been read into Dask DataFrame objects using `dd.read_fwf()`, then I transform a string field on one of the frames, then join (merge) on that field.

Comment: The dask.distributed docs have a [section](https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/killed.html) explaining what a killed worker means. To help beyond this, we'll definitely need to see your code.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain memory constraints for a particular worker, which you can read from here : https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/worker-memory.html .
Apart from this, you can try increasing the number of workers, threads while initializing the dask client.